# Why httpbuilder is not giving the exact JSON output?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am trying to get the projectid of my project from JIRA using gradle script.I wrote few methods which basically try to get the JSON output and fetch the project id of that particular project but now i am not able to get the projectId from that. Below is the methods which i am using to get the JSON result. it's working fine but not giving me the exact JSON output.My project Name is TESTPROJECT and id is 12345.I am looking when you have fresh project and need to get the projectid of that project using JIRA request method.I pasted the below JSON output which doesn't have {} "" so not exactly JSON output.Can someone tell me how could I get the project id with below way or am I doing something wrong?

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
    classpath 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1'
    classpath 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
  }
}

ext {
  jiraURL = "https://test.test.com/"
  jiraProject = 'TESTPROJECT'
  jiraUser = "test"
  jiraPassword = "*****"
}


import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType

def String authHeader() {
  String userAndPassword = "${jiraUser}:${jiraPassword}"
  String authHeader = 'Basic ' + userAndPassword.getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
  return authHeader
}

/*
 * Get the Jira project details 
 */
def Map getJiraprojectDetails(String projectName) {
  Map json = jiraProjectRequest(
    "project/${projectName}",
    groovyx.net.http.Method.GET,
    null,
    'Get JIRA version failure - getJiraprojectDetails()'
  )
   existingProjectId = json.key.id[0]

  if (existingProjectId == null || existingProjectId == 0)
    throw new GradleException("Project was not found in JIRA")

  return existingProjectId
}
def Map jiraProjectRequest(String path, groovyx.net.http.Method method, Map jsonBody, String failMessage) {
  Map jsonResult = null
  def jira = new HTTPBuilder("${jiraURL}/rest/api/2/${path}", ContentType.JSON)
  jira.request(method) { req ->
    headers.'Authorization' = authHeader()
    requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
    if (body != null)
      body = jsonBody

    response.success = { resp, json ->
      println "$json"
      jsonResult = json
      println "$jsonResult"
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
      String message = "${failMessage}: ${resp.status} - ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}"
      throw new GradleException(message)
    }
  }

  return jsonResult
}

def void makeNewversion() {
  def projectName = "${jiraProject}"
  println "$projectName"
  projectid = getJiraprojectDetails(projectName)
}


task createJiraVersion() {
  doLast {
    if (project.hasProperty('createVersion')) {
     makeNewversion()
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON Output**

```
[jira] Response data: -----
[jira] [expand:description,lead,url,projectKeys, self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352, id:48352, key:TESTPROJECT, description:, lead:[self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/user?username=C56765, key:C56765, name:C56765, avatarUrls:[48x48:https://test.test1.com/secure/useravatar?ownerId=C56765&avatarId=42213, 24x24:https://test.test1.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=C56765&avatarId=42213, 16x16:https://test.test1.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=h156765&avatarId=42213, 32x32:https://test.test1.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=C56765&avatarId=42213], displayName:karry test, active:true], components:[], issueTypes:[[self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/1, id:1, description:A problem which impairs or prevents the functions or performance of the product or its related artifacts. It can be related to software, hardware or both., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31313&avatarType=issuetype, name:Defect, subtask:false, avatarId:31313], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/66, id:66, description:Created by JIRA Software - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a big user story that needs to be broken down., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31317&avatarType=issuetype, name:Epic, subtask:false, avatarId:31317], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/67, id:67, description:Created by JIRA Software - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a user story., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31325&avatarType=issuetype, name:Story, subtask:false, avatarId:31325], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/10600, id:10600, description:, iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31324&avatarType=issuetype, name:Initiative, subtask:false, avatarId:31324], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/2, id:2, description:A new feature of the product., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31321&avatarType=issuetype, name:New Feature, subtask:false, avatarId:31321], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/4, id:4, description:An enhancement to an existing feature., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31320&avatarType=issuetype, name:Improvement, subtask:false, avatarId:31320], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/25, id:25, description:A formal request to change an existing, baselined project artifact. , iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31330&avatarType=issuetype, name:Change Request, subtask:false, avatarId:31330], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/3, id:3, description:A task that needs to be done., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31328&avatarType=issuetype, name:Task, subtask:false, avatarId:31328], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/26, id:26, description:A risk is an uncertain future event or condition, with a probability of occurrence, and a potential for loss., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31318&avatarType=issuetype, name:Risk, subtask:false, avatarId:31318], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/87, id:87, description:An impediment is something that makes it difficult to do or complete something in a project and thus requires action. It may be a project risks that has occurred and typically represents something upon which a decision and actions are needed. The decision may not necessarily change the scope, schedule or cost of the project but the lack of a decision would affect the schedule., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31318&avatarType=issuetype, name:Impediment, subtask:false, avatarId:31318], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/8, id:8, description:An item discussed in a meeting that requires further action or work., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31328&avatarType=issuetype, name:Action Item, subtask:false, avatarId:31328], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/83, id:83, description:, iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31314&avatarType=issuetype, name:Root Cause Analysis, subtask:false, avatarId:31314], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/58, id:58, description:Any issue, solution or improvement learned in a project that should be shared with other people and/or projects., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31324&avatarType=issuetype, name:Lesson Learned, subtask:false, avatarId:31324], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/39, id:39, description:A summary of a meeting including participants, decisions, and resulting actions., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=39910&avatarType=issuetype, name:Meeting Minutes, subtask:false, avatarId:39910], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/55, id:55, description:An item for managing a review consisting of one or more review findings., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31323&avatarType=issuetype, name:Review, subtask:false, avatarId:31323], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/43, id:43, description:Used to track and manage Process Compliance and Configuration Audits on a project., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=42820&avatarType=issuetype, name:Audit, subtask:false, avatarId:42820], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/63, id:63, description:Used for requesting the approval of a particular work product and collecting approval from multiple individuals., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31316&avatarType=issuetype, name:Approval Request, subtask:false, avatarId:31316], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/5, id:5, description:A task that needs to be done., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31328&avatarType=issuetype, name:Sub-Task, subtask:true, avatarId:31328], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/35, id:35, description:An item discussed in a meeting that requires further action or work., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31328&avatarType=issuetype, name:Action Item (Sub-Issue), subtask:true, avatarId:31328], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/56, id:56, description:A defect, question, suggestion or other issue resulting from the review of a document or other artifact. , iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31323&avatarType=issuetype, name:Review Finding, subtask:true, avatarId:31323], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/62, id:62, description:, iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/images/icons/issuetypes/documentation.png, name:Mitigation Plan, subtask:true], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/61, id:61, description:An issue (non-compliance, recommendation) found during an audit., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31323&avatarType=issuetype, name:Audit Finding, subtask:true, avatarId:31323], [self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/64, id:64, description:A sub-issue type used for capturing the approval (or disapproval) of an individual for a particular work product., iconUrl:https://test.test1.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=31316&avatarType=issuetype, name:Approval, subtask:true, avatarId:31316]], assigneeType:PROJECT_LEAD, versions:[[self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/version/98423, id:98423, name:TCD 1.2.3, archived:false, released:false, projectId:48352]], name:Test PAAS, roles:[CCB:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10020, L1 Support:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10050, Developers:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10001, Approvers:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10052, Administrators:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10002, Watcher:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10030, Bulkcloners:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10070, Testers:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10010, Users:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10000, L2 Support:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/48352/role/10051], avatarUrls:[48x48:https://test.test1.com/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=39413, 24x24:https://test.test1.com/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=39413, 16x16:https://test.test1.com/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=39413, 32x32:https://test.test1.com/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=39413], projectCategory:[self:https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/projectCategory/18032, id:18032, name:Solutions, description:TO-12179], projectTypeKey:software]
```

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: If I try to do the https://test.test1.com/rest/api/2/project/TESTPROJECT/   I get the valid JSON output

Comment: I added my jirarequest method which is giving me the JSON format

Comment: It's `json.id`.

Comment: could you please explain littler more?

Comment: Okay, I'm just saying that `[expand:description,lead,url,projectKeys` is not valid JSON. Something like `{ "expand" : "description,lead,url,projectKeys"`  is

Comment: Yes that's true not able to understand why it is not giving me the exact output

Comment: Am I doing something wrong in my jirarequest method?

Comment: If you call how you call your API, then HTTPBuilder will parse the JSON for you and give you a Map.  From that map, you can do `json.id` to get the `id` key from your `json` Map.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to get the project id

```
/*
 * Get the Jira project ID for a project like 'ABC'
 */
def int getJiraProjectid(String jiraProject) {

 int existingProjectId = 0

  def json = [jiraprojectRequest()]
  json.each {
    existingProjectId = it."id".toInteger()
    //println "$existingVersionId"
 }
  if (existingProjectId == 0)
   throw new GradleException("Existing project ${jiraProject} was not found in JIRA")

 return existingProjectId
}

def Map jiraprojectRequest() {
  Map jsonResultList = null
  def jira = new HTTPBuilder("${jiraURL}/rest/api/2/project/${jiraProject}", ContentType.JSON)
  jira.request(groovyx.net.http.Method.GET) { req ->
    headers.'Authorization' = authHeader()

    response.success = { resp, json ->
      project.getLogger().info('[jira] Response data: -----')
      project.getLogger().info("[jira] $json")
      project.getLogger().info('\n--------------------')
      jsonResultList = json
    }

    response.failure = { resp ->
      throw new GradleException("Get JIRA versions failure - jiraGetVersions(): ${resp.status} - ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}")
    }
  }
  return jsonResultList
}
```